# Increase a recive buffer in UDP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I'wm writing an app, which transmits video and obviously uses UDP protocol fot this purpose.
So I am wondering how can I increase a size of send/recieve buffer, cause currently the maximal size of data, which I can send is 65000 bytes.
I already tried to do it in following way:

```
int option = 262144;
if(setsockopt(m_SocketHandle,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF ,(char*)&option,sizeof(option)) < 0)
{
    printf("setsockopt failed\n");

}
```

But it did not work. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I do it?

You can't. The maximum size of an IPv4 UDP datagram is 65535-20-8=65507 bytes. Increasing the buffer size cannot change that. Datagrams larger than the path MTU (< 1500 bytes) will be fragmented, and fragmented datagrams are more likely to be lost, statistically, so using datagram sizes up around 64k is contra-indicated anyway.